Background color shifting in html2canvas img and pdf react
React JS
I am using html2canvas to convert a div to image and then pdf, however in the image and pdf view the background color of elements is shifting and hence the bottom part of text is being clipped.
initial look

After converted to image/pdf
using
(on click of button, function invoked)
const pdf = new jsPDF({
  orientation: 'portrait',
  unit: 'mm',
  format: 'a4',
});
html2canvas(page, { scale: 1 }) // Set scale to 1 to disable scaling
      .then(canvas => {
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'))
        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save('page.pdf');
      });
  };

// sample HTML

<span id="dragDiv" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} className='bg-pink-500 cursor-move' style={{ userSelect: 'none', position: 'absolute' }}>
fcnejkd


styles of div (any component) => {parent div => relative, target=> absolute (to allow drag and change position)


Tailwind CSS sets the display property of the img tag to display: block; during preflight. This introduces a line-break below the element which is not seen in the UI render. But, when you convert the same HTML to Image using html2canvas, the line-break gets rendered thus adding an unnecessary space in the resulting image. To solve this, we can add the following code to the tailwind.css file.
@layer base {
  img {
    @apply inline-block;
  }
}

Here is the initial answer:
html2canvas shifting text downwards
